# Rest API call from REACT APP always return isLoaded: false

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      items: [],
      isLoaded: false
    };
  }

  callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/process/4570")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: false,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  componetDidMount() {
    this.callAPI();
  }


  render() {
    var { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
    else {

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <ul>
            {items.map(item => (
              <li key={item.id} >
                Id: {item.id} | Name: {item.name}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
export default App;
```

console: no error.
react-developer-tool: returns
state=
{
"error": null,
"items": [],
"isLoaded": false
}

I am very new to REACT and APIs. Please guide me through, what mistake i have done here. I am unable to get the API output.
I am always getting "Loading"

The API does return the json:
{"id":"4570","name":"AR_RESUME_CNC_ROUTING"}

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `isLoading` to true in your `callApi` function before every thing else, after that you need to set it false when you get the result or when you catch some error.

```
callAPI() {

    this.setState({
      isLoading: true,
    });

    fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/process/4570")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }
```

a bit explanation about the code, you always want to show loading when your api call begins, thats why we set `isLoading` in the beginning of the function, then when we get the result (success or failure, does not matter) the loading state should change to false, because we have at least a result!

also as an extra point you can use `try {...} catch {...} finally {...}` to have better code style like below:

```
async callApi() {

  try {
    
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })

    const result = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/process/4570")
    const data = await result.json()
    
    this.setState({
       items: result.items
    });
   
  } catch (e) {
    this.setState({ error: e })
  } finally {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
  }

}
```

Comment: Note that it's `isLoaded`, not `isLoading` :-)

Comment: also you need to change the `else if (!isLoaded) {` to `else if (isLoaded) {`

Comment: I meant that the variable, as used in the question, doesn't represent "is currently loading", but "has finished loading" - quite the opposite of your example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me it is some sort of scope issue. You are doing:

```
this.setState({
    isLoaded: true,
    items: result.items
});
```

but you are calling it within the function callback of the fetch promise. So, `this` is probably referencing the internal Promise object.

I recommend you try this:

```
callAPI() {
    const self = this;
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/process/4570")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          self.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          self.setState({
            isLoaded: false,
            error
          });
        }
      )
   }
```

Re-reference the this, to a new variable (in this case I used self) and try your code there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, however the solution which worked for me is as below:

```
class GetOnlinePosts extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            loading: true,
            posts: null,
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        console.log("inside external_json");
        const url = "http://localhost:4000/api/process/4570";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ posts: data, loading: false })
        console.log(data);
    }
```

...........